# How do I structure a NoSQL schema so that I can query for records based on a record property?

Tags: nosql, redis

Am playing around with various NoSQL databases (redis and couchdb primarily), and have come across a problem:

If I save user data like so:

`SET user:5 "{name: \"foobar\", age: 26}"`

I can always retrieve it with `GET user:5`. However, what if I didn't know the user's id but *did* know their `name`, and wanted to query to find out the `id`?

Some ideas we were kicking around involved sending `SET usernames:foobar "5"` at the same time as the other `SET`, but because they are not related like in an RDBMS, sloppy code could accidentally cause a data mismatch.

Is there a "standard" way of handling a procedure like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you described is pretty much the standard way in Redis.

You are essentially creating an index on usernames. Other systems automatically create such indexes for you, and maintain them as the data changes. With Redis, you have to do that on your own.

Yes, sloppy code will result in data mismatch. That is the cost you pay every time you denormalize or create indexes. You just have to be careful about it.

Comment: Thank you @sripathi-krishnan. We've adopted this approach, so fingers crosses we don't regret it later!